# Haskell, forM - why this code returns such result?

Tags: haskell, monads

I was very surprised when I saw it:

```
forM [5,6] (\x -> x:[7])
[[5,6],[5,7],[7,6],[7,7]]
```

**I would like to get** `[[5,7], [6,7]]`. I know that it is possible to get it using map, but I am learning monads now.
I make a next step, and try:

```
forM [5,6] (\x -> print x)
5
6
[(),()]
```

What does it mean? `[(), ()]` is at least strange. Could you explain me this issue ?

Comment: just use `map` instead of `forM` (switch arguments of course) - list-monads are supposed to combine every value ;)

Comment: Ok, but can you give some comment ?

Comment: well it's in the definition of the list-monad - the second one happens because the *output* / value of the IO computation you get is a list of two unit-values (one from each print) - if you don't want to know use `forM_` there

Comment: Worth noting, in the common scenario where you feed `mapM`/`forM` a function which return `m ()`, it's often better to use the `mapM_`/`forM_` relatives. These behave almost identically but don't bother to build up a list as a result because a list of `()`s is almost never helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### regarding your strange `[(),()]`

for the second one remember: `print` is `Show a => a -> IO ()` (and has the sideeffect of printing out the value with `show`)

now

```
forM [5,6] print -- same as yours
= mapM print [5,6]
= sequence $ fmap print [5,6]
= sequence [print 5, print 6]
```

now for the sideeffects: `sequence` in the `IO` monad will just compute one after the other

but for the *result* it's `[(),()]` (remember: `sqeuence :: [IO a] -> IO [a]`)

so you get first the sideeffects (`5` and `6` printed on newlines) and then the result of this computation `[(),()]`

#### getting rid of it:

you can get rid of this by using `forM_` instead (which will give `()` back):

```
> import Control.Monad(forM_)
> forM_ [5,6] print
5
6
```

---

### regarding the list-monad

you can see why the first from this:

```
forM [5,6] (\x -> x:[7])
= mapM (\x -> x:[7]) [5,6]
= sequence (fmap (\...) [5,6])
= sequence [[5,7],[6,7]]
= [[5,6],[5,7],[7,6],[7,7]]
```

remember - the list-monad is basically doing the cross-product there

Answer (score 1):

`print 5` is a value of type `IO ()`, an action that does I/O and that finally returns a value of type `()` (there is only one such value: `()`).

`forM list print` executes `print` an every value in `list`, and *returns* the list of their return values. This is a list of `()`, which is why you see a final `[(),...,()]`.By comparison `forM_ list print` will not return a list of results, but a single ().

Note that GHCi special-cases `IO ()` actions, in that GHCi does not print the final `()` result. This is not the case for e.g. `IO [()]` actions, so GHCi will print the final list at the end.